# blob not showing up on depthjs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, kinect, openkinect

i have installed the plugin on chorme (22.0) on mac(10.7.4). The kinect works find on the OpenNI samples, and when i got to the test page http://steventking.com/gesture_interface_site/BasicDemo.html it shows both kinect and plugin are in place. but no hand in view.

The blob is not showing up on any page. when i check the background.html it gives me this error:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
```

Depthjs seems to be running,

```
depthjspluginAPI: start DepthJS backend.js:142
depthjsplugin::RunDepthJS backend.js:142
depthjsplugin::RunDepthJS - thread running? backend.js:142
Successfully acquired Kinect event monitor from plugin! backend.js:145
Init complete root.js:48
OpenNIBackend: start openni backend thread undefined:1
event port connected chrome.js:14
```

But i keep getting this assertion failed error, which is kinda beyond my understanding.

```
Assertion failed: chrome.js:13
(anonymous function) chrome.js:13
chrome.Event.dispatchToListener event_bindings:379
chrome.Event.dispatch_ event_bindings:365
chrome.Event.dispatch event_bindings:385
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnConnect
```

I have the feeling that the kinect is working as the red light is on (just like it does when i run those openNI samples) but as the blobs not showing up i cannot trace my hand or do anything. Anyone has similar issue here?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you've posted is telling you that inline script blocks are disallowed inside of Chrome Extensions. Take a look at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html for some detail about the restrictions, and how you can tweak your extensions to run in the brave new world of manifest version 2 and Content Security Policy. In particular, the [section on inline script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution) should come in handy.